# save filename and headertext value as key value pair collection

Tags: c#

given the following text file:

```
Find all "HeaderText="", Subfolders, Find Results 1, "Entire Solution"
  C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx(16):                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" ReadOnly="True" 
  C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx(18):                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
  C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx(20):                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="ContactName" 
  Matching lines: 3    Matching files: 1    Total files searched: 5
```

what's the best way to put just the filename and the value of HeaderText in a collection?

```
for example,

var test = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();

test.Add(Default.aspx, CustomerID);
test.Add(Default.aspx, CompanyName);
test.Add(Default.aspx, ContactName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expressions:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Parse(StreamReader reader)
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var tokens = Regex.Split(line, @"\(\d+\)\:");
        if (tokens.Length > 1)
        {
            var file = Path.GetFileName(tokens[0]);
            var match = Regex.Match(tokens[1], @"HeaderText=\""(\w+)\""");
            if (match.Success)
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                    file, match.Groups[1].Value
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which could be called like this:

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText("test.txt"))
{
    foreach (var item in Parse(reader))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("file: {0}, header: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: just testing this out with Visual Studio find and replace (Ctrl+Shft+H) using using the Regular Expressions option I tried pasting "HeaderText=\""(\w+)\"" but it didn't find anything? Should have found 3 results

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) rather than a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` to hold your pairs. The `NameValueCollection` can have more than one entry per key.

If the file is not extremely large you can do the following:

1. Read the file using [System.IO.File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) and perform
   steps 2-4 on each valid line in the array.
2. Get the filename from the full path using [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx).
3. Parse the String using `IndexOf` and `Substring` to get the
   HeaderText value.
4. Add the pair to the `NameValueCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another regular expression solution, this one uses named groups:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Process(string fileContents)
{
    const string regexPattern = @"\\(?<filename>[\w\.]+)\(.*HeaderText=""(?<headerText>\w+)""";

    var matches = Regex.Matches(fileContents, regexPattern);

    var test = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        var fileName = match.Groups["filename"].Value;
        var headerText = match.Groups["headerText"].Value;

        test.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(fileName, headerText));
    }

    return test;
}
```