# regular expression for spaces and words

Tags: c#

have the following text file:

```
<div>
    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Hello World of Regular Expression" />
</div>
```

How do i get what's between the double quotes for any word and spaces?

**Updated:**

```
//This one gets me close but doesn't get me strings with spaces in them
var match = Regex.Match(tokens[1], @"HeaderText=\""(\w+)\"""); 
//This was suggested below. It shows correct match count but values are just empty strings
var match = Regex.Match(tokens[1], @"HeaderText=""[^""]+""|[\w]+");

if (match.Success)
{
    yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
        file, match.Groups[1].Value //This is empty for 2nd scenario
    );
}
```

Comment: Don't parse html with Regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/426894

Comment: It's not really Html but ASP which will produce Html. He may want to parse it before it's generated.

Comment: @Daok: It makes no difference at all. HTML could also be parsed with an XML parser, which is what "the correct" approach is in these cases.

Comment: @Daok You got it. I am searching for maintenance purposes and not as part of application of sort

Comment: @rod Can you run the regex against the HeaderText property of the field directly in code behind?

Comment: @Rod Gotcha. You'll want to use a proper Html parsing engine then for sure, not regular expressions.  Here's a free easy to use library that should work great for this purpose: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Jon It makes a difference as you can see rod answer after yours. Have a nice day.

Comment: sorry all, correction: all i'm doing is collecting all strings related to HeaderText and putting them in a generic collection. See this post for the actual data file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779790/save-filename-and-headertext-value-as-key-value-pair-collection  -- It's not a html file it just happens to have html syntax

Comment: @rod It would be helpful to include that sort of information upfront. I still think though, that you'll be better off with a proper html parser, using it to grab the HeaderText property text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
"[^"]+"|[\w]+
```

This will return a list of matches, of the individual words AND the entire expression between quotes.

Comment: how about escaped quotes characters in the string ?